# Assign unique id to component as it renders using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I recently started learning how to use Redux as a way to manage state in my applications and I like it so far, but I'm having trouble assigning props dynamically to to children of a parent component.

Here is what I am working with, basic parent with children scenario:

```
<Layout>
  <Child />
  <Child />
  <Child />
</Layout>
```

I want each child to have a unique id so `childProps.id` for the first child would be `1`, the second child would be `2` and so on.

First here is the `assignId` function I want to fire when the component is rendered:

```
export function assignId(number){
  return{
    type: "ASSIGN",
    payload: number
  }
}
```

Here is the reducer listening for this function:

```
export default function reducer(state={

            id: 0

        }, action){

      switch (action.type){
        case "ASSIGN": {
          return {...state, id: action.payload}
        }
      }

  return state

}
```

Finally the `<Child />` component itself:

```
import React from "react";

import { activeBox, beginSession, unselect, assignId } from '../actions/boxActions'

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  
  componentWillMount(){
    var i = 1

    this.props.dispatch(assignId(i));

    i++

  }

  render(){

    return (
    <div className="box"></div>
    )
  }
}
```

`componentWillMount` works. I have `var i = 1` it sets `childProps.id` to 1 for *all* of my `<Child />` components. Simply, how would I make a function that makes each `childProps.id` unique for each `<Child />` component based on it's order within the `<Layout />` parent?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're adding complexity with zero value. The `id` attribute of a DOM element has for sure to be unique, so you're on a right track, however

- in React, you don't manage elements by their IDs; take a look at [references to corresponding DOM elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) instead,
- generating a globally unique identifier comes at cost of maintaining that generating function, and
- if you plan to have an arbitrary number of `Child` components coming from somewhere and being reflected from an iterable, why not using `Array#map`?

So

```
render() {
  const childElements = [1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Child id="1" />
      <Child id="2" />
      <Child id="3" />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

turns into

```
render() {
  const childElements = [1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <Layout>
      {childElements.map((id, index) => (
        <Child
          key={index}
          id={id} />
      ))}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

From your code, I can see that you want to dispatch an action to assign an element with an ID, while that ID isn't even stored anywhere. If it really isn't stored and used for any purpose, there's no need in it.

A general rule in React is to make things simple, not complicated. You have data, you reflect this data into DOM using components (and the hierarchy they form), and that's it. If you need to listen to DOM events, you use `onClick`, `onChange` and other [props that are bound to DOM event listeners](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html), and that's it. Once you want to use a lib that works with DOM, try to stick to refs instead of `id`s, because those are guaranteed to refer to existing DOM element, and reference by `id` may lead to nowhere when a component is being updated.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what others are saying, it makes good sense to assign IDs to array items in the store. When you render them you can pass this ID as the `key` prop to each child component. This starts to make great sense when you insert, delete or reorder array items. React will use this key to help it find the right component that matches the array item. This can speed up rendering massively when store item indices change around.

This is the reason the `key` prop exists and it's also why you should not simply use the index of the item. The index isn't the same thing as the identity.

Now, to generate and store such a unique ID, do something like this:

```
let nextId = 0;

function addItem(item) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
    payload: {
      ...item, 
      id: nextId++
    }
  };
}

function reducer(state = [], action) {
  switch action.type {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return [...state, action.payload]
      break; 
    default:
       return state; 
  }
}
```

You can then assign this ID to the key prop of each child. It'll be unique for the session and that's all you probably need. If not you can generate any other ID you like, such as a GUID. In any case, the important thing is that you want the ID to be a part of the item from the beginning and that the ID is not and should not be assigned to the component, but to the item the component is going to display. The component assumes the identity of the item found in the store and not the other way around.

Comment: Using global variables is bad bad bad. Why not referring to a certain property of state and increasing it immutably?

Comment: Using global variables is not always a terrible thing. Note that even if multiple parts of the app use this function, it won't clash because the IDs are still unique. Also, it's trivial to put this variable in a closure so it's no longer global. It would still function the same though. Deriving the ID from state could work but note that the ID should be a part of the item create action so that replayability is preserved. In any case, check Dan Abramov's todo example and see that he uses a global variable as well. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/actions/index.js

Answer (score 1):

At the parent level, get your children IDs in an array, loop through them, and assign the id as a prop of the child.

Something like this:

```
<Layout>
  {childrenIds.map((i) => { return <Child id={i} />} )}
</Layout>
```